# human handoff bot sample not running

Tags: c#, botframework

I was trying to run [this github](https://github.com/ankitbko/human-handoff-bot) bot framework sample but I am getting error.

I have configured Bot on Bot Framework Portal, add botID, AppID, AppPwd in web.config, enabled Directline, configured ngrok.

As soon as I am opening index.html page I am getting following error.

> JavaScript critical error at line 83, column 32 in
>   http://localhost:3979/agentdashboard/index.html?s=DIRECTLINEKEY\n\nSCRIPT1002:
>   Syntax error

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Did you set the DirectLineKey in the url?

Comment: yes, i did. Removed from her for simplicity.

Comment: Did you file an issue against that repository?

Comment: Yes I have logged an issue

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript critical error at line 83, column 32 in http://localhost:3979/agentdashboard/index.html?s=DIRECTLINEKEY\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error

I checked the JavaScript code written in `index.html`, and I find that the [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are used. Such as:

```
const connect = () => {
    var name;
    if(!connected)
        name = "connect"
    else
        name = "disconnect"
    botConnection
        .postActivity({type: "event", value: "", from: user, name: name})
        .subscribe(connectionSuccess);
};
```

If you are using the browser that does not support it, which will cause Syntax error.

***Same error in Internet Explorer:***

[image]

Please refer to **Browser compatibility** of [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and browse `index.html` in the browser that supports arrow function expression to check if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @NikhilGupta, any updates? do you check if arrow function causes the Syntax error?